# Boot loader won't load

Tags: boot, 14.04, windows-8, bootloader

I think it is the OS boot manager because it is the first item on "Boot Order". Any ways when Ubuntu loads the first screen I get has purple edges around it (this must be the boot-loader). I don't know any of the LiveCD stuff... I just want to boot Windows 8 without virtual box. It doesn't matter if my stuff is on it or not. I either want to restore Windows 8 or load it.

Answer (score 0):

Just an inkling, but hold [Shift] as you start the computer, just before it shows you this screen. IF you get any options, it might be the Ubuntu kernel experiencing issues. If nothing changes, then it could be a major issue with GRUB (the OS bootloader).